usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary crash
I m running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Let me begin with saying that I am a very basic PC user and also have almost zero knowledge of Linux (I installed it for the first time a few months ago).
On start-up I get this crash.
Screenshot1
Screenshot2
I have no clue on what I should do, but happy to share more info with you if you need.
